# Get linked entities with many-to-many link to themselves?

Tags: ios, core-data, many-to-many, entity-relationship

I have something similar to the following situation:

[image]

The problem is when I added a link from one object to another then I added it once. So if 2 objects are linked then one has `directReports == 1`, managers = 0 and another `directReports == 0`, `managers == 1`.

And if I want to get all the linked objects then I can't write a predicate as `(directReports.count > 0) OR (managers.count > 0)` (it is forbidden). So I should write it as `(ANY directReports != nil) OR (ANY managers != nil)`.

So are there better ways to solve this issue. For example I saw that it is possible to create a category over entity but can I use it in a predicate?

Comment: What exactly do you want to fetch? All objects that are linked to any other object?

Comment: all objects that are linked to any other object of the same type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both predicates

```
(directReports.@count > 0) OR (managers.@count > 0)
```

(note that it is **"@count"**, not **"count"**) and

```
(ANY directReports != nil) OR (ANY managers != nil)
```

should work to fetch all employees that are linked to any other employee
(via one of the two relationships).

A category method does not help, because a predicate for a (SQLite based) Core Data
fetch request can only use persistent attributes, but not transient attributes or
Objective-C methods.

Comment: Thanks for @count, but I hoped to hear is it possible to replace "condition1 OR condition2" with "condition3" (without or, and and similar)

Comment: @user2083364: I don't think that is possible. - And a category method does not help, because predicates in a Core Data fetch request can only use *persistent* properties. So the only alternative would be that you add another attribute `totalCount` which has to be updated each time a relationship is added or removed. I doubt that it is worth the hassle.